# Using Yup to validate credit card details

Tags: javascript, yup

I'm using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate a signup form but I'm struggling to validate the credit card fields due to needing methods from both Yup's `string` and `number` schema.

Card number for example should not exceed 16 characters. This is easily achievable using the `max` method from the `string` schema. However, if the user typed in 16 letters rather than numbers this would currently pass validation. If I change the schema from `string` to `number` then `max` doesn't behave in the same way and instead adds up all the numbers in the field and checks to see if it equates to less than the max number.

An example of a field where I would need to use the `min` and `max` methods of the `number` schema is the expiry month where the min would be 1 and the max would be 12. However, I still need to check to make sure that the number of characters is in this field is 2 as a leading 0 should be used for the months January to September.

```
const validationSchema = {
  cardNumber: Yup.string()
    .label('Card number')
    .max(16)
    .required(),
  cvc: Yup.string()
    .label('CVC')
    .min(3)
    .max(4)
    .required(),
  nameOnCard: Yup.string()
    .label('Name on card')
    .required(),
  expiryMonth: Yup.string()
    .label('Expiry month')
    .min(2)
    .max(2)
    .required(),
  expiryYear: Yup.string()
    .label('Expiry year')
    .min(4)
    .max(4)
    .required(),
};
```

Answer (score 34):

Instead of doing validation like this, you can use Yup's test method and return `true` or `false` given by third-party validators. For example: `braintree/card-validator`.
So, it would look something like this:

```
import valid from 'card-validator'; //import statement

CreditCardNumber: 
Yup
    .string()
    .test('test-number', // this is used internally by yup
    'Credit Card number is invalid', //validation message
     value => valid.number(value).isValid) // return true false based on validation
    .required()
```

There are also `valid.expirationDate(value).isValid`, `valid.cvv(value).isValid` and `valid.postalCode(value).isValid`

#### https://github.com/braintree/card-validator

#### https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I used [Yup's `.test()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema) method for validating a credit card's expiration in the past.

1) I had to use a mask, and by using a mask the DOM element I had to use was a single input field. The mask looks like this `__/__` (two underscores separated by a forward slash)

At first, the validation started off as:

```
export const expirationDate = Yup.string()
  .typeError('Not a valid expiration date. Example: MM/YY')
  .max(5, 'Not a valid expiration date. Example: MM/YY')
  .matches(
    /([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})/,
    'Not a valid expiration date. Example: MM/YY'
  )
  .required('Expiration date is required')
```

Even though there was server-side validation, I should still do the work to prevent bad inputs such as: `13/19` or `99/99`. Why waste a roundtrip network call. So, in between the `.matches()` and `.required()` method calls I added:

```
.test(
    'test-credit-card-expiration-date',
    'Invalid Expiration Date has past',
    expirationDate => {
      if (!expirationDate) {
        return false
      }

      const today = new Date()
      const monthToday = today.getMonth() + 1
      const yearToday = today
        .getFullYear()
        .toString()
        .substr(-2)

      const [expMonth, expYear] = expirationDate.split('/')

      if (Number(expYear) < Number(yearToday)) {
        return false
      } else if (
        Number(expMonth) < monthToday &&
        Number(expYear) <= Number(yearToday)
      ) {
        return false
      }

      return true
    }
  )
  .test(
    'test-credit-card-expiration-date',
    'Invalid Expiration Month',
    expirationDate => {
      if (!expirationDate) {
        return false
      }
      const today = new Date()
        .getFullYear()
        .toString()
        .substr(-2)

      const [expMonth] = expirationDate.split('/')

      if (Number(expMonth) > 12) {
        return false
      }

      return true
    }
  )
```

references:

- [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [Sgnl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763772/11283521) to test if the exp month is valid you can do so with a simple regex too.

As it follows:

```
const exp = Yup.string()
    .matches(/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$/g, 'Invalid expiration date');
```

Breakdown:

- `^`. Means "from the beginning of the string". We are forcing the regex to validate from this point, otherwise it would look for any instance of this happening anywhere on the string.
- `0[1-9]`. We validate a range between 01-09.
- `|`. Works as an `OR` operator.
- `1[0-2]`. Matches a range between 10-12, the rest of the months we needed. This whole operation is encased between parentheses to group the operation.
- `\/`. We are escaping the '/' character.
- `\d`. Matches any digit
- `{2}`. `{n}` Means "`n` of the preceding". In this case "Two of the preceding" where the preceding was the digit `\d` expression.
- `$`. Means "end of string". We're testing the string from start to end to match this exact pattern.